# Built-in (or Terse) Method to Combine and Transpose Datasets

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset, associations

From some calculations I have ended with `Dataset`s of the form:

```
{ds1, ds2} = Dataset /@ {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|10 -> 3, 20 -> 4|>}
```

[image]

I would like to combine and transpose these as you can do with lists (e.g. `Transpose[{list1, list2}]`).  I tried `Transpose[<|Normal@ds1, Normal@ds2|>]` which doesn't work but the following does:

```
Apply[Association, Transpose[(Normal@# /. {Association -> List}) & /@ {ds1, ds2}], {1}]
(* {<|"a" -> 1, 10 -> 3|>, <|"b" -> 2, 20 -> 4|>} *)
```

However, these seems overly verbose for such a simple transpose.  Is there a built-in function that I have missed? Or some terser (yet readable) combination of functions?

Comment: How about `MapThread[Association, Normal@*Normal /@ {ds1, ds2}]`?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Very nice! (+1) I knew I was missing something.

Comment: Ok, I decided to make it an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about a built-in, but you can do

```
MapThread[Association, Normal@*Normal /@ {ds1, ds2}]
```

> ```
> {<|"a" -> 1, 10 -> 3|>, <|"b" -> 2, 20 -> 4|>}
> ```